# minicom/picocom does not transfer files using zmodem to embedded linux board

Tags: embedded-linux, zmodem

I have a embedded linux device based on DM368 processor from TI with the kernel version 2.6.32.17 and BusyBox v1.13.2 (2011-03-24 18:58:44 CDT) file system.

I have problem with transferring files from my computer (ubuntu 14.04) into the board using zmodem in minicom/picocom over serial port.

Problem is that when I send a file using zmodem in minicom or picocom it says that timeout happened and "Transfer Incomplete". Do I have to run some sort of daemon or program on the board?

zmodem is supposed to be very simple and I've never had a problem with zmodem and embedded linux boards.

Here is the output of picocom after pressing ^A +S and entering the file path and name:

[picocom zmodem error.png](http://postimg.org/image/wd1r05jx1/)

And this is minicom output after pressing ^A +S and selecting desired file:

```
     +-----------[zmodem upload - Press CTRL-C to quit]------------+                                   
     |RROR                                                         |                                   
     |oot@dm368-evm:/home# Retry 0: Got ZNAK                       |                                   
     |-sh: Retry 0: Got ZNAK                                       |                                   
     | not foundroot@dm368-evm:/home#                              |                                   
     |Transfer incomplete                                          |                                   
     |                                                             |                                   
     | READY: press any key to continue...                         |                                   
     +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What is wrong?

Comment: *"Do I have to run some sort of daemon or program on the board?"* -- You most certainly do.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042023/u-boot-flash-emmc-ttl-serial/28053750#28053750 for receiving by U-Boot.  For receiving while the kernel is up and running, then cross-compile and install the [lrzsz program](https://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I want to transfer files using minicom while kernel is up and running. So I have cross compiled lrzsz packege and got two binaries named lrz and lsz. Now what am I supposed to do after copying them to the board?

Comment: *"Now what am I supposed to do..."* -- Did you find/read any documentation in the source package (e.g. **man** pages)?  Did you guess that `lrz` is for receiving and `lsz` is for sending?  Did you try `lrz --help`?

Comment: Yes I figured that lrz is for receiving! It's just that first I cross compiled it and I wasn't able to run lrz --help on my computer and the board wasn't around that time so I couldn't get to see its help or man or whatever! Anyway now I ran lrz on the board and I managed to send files to the board using zmodem in minicom. But it's kind of slow and I didn't see any options to set bps for lrz and I don't know on what bps it's working! Is there any options to speed it up? My minicom is configured to work with 115200.

Comment: Besides I have to run lrz on the board first but in another board I just can send files through minicom and zmodem without having to run anything first on the board. I don't know how is that possible. Anyway how can I automate this process? Should I put lrz in start-up or something?

Comment: Ok I figured how to run lrz automatically through minicom when you select zmodem in minicom to transfer a file. You just have to rename lrz and lsz to rz and sz respectively and put them into /usr/bin directory. This way whenever you transfer a file using zmodem the rz program runs automatically and handles that file. But the speed is kind of slower than the other boards I have tested before even though they had rz and sz and their terminal was configured for 115200 like this board too. So I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to sawdust I could figure this out. The problem simply was that I didn't have rz and sz programs installed in the right directory. Apparently minicom or to be more exact zmodem needs these programs and calls them every time you want to send or receive files. So one has to cross compile lrzsz package like this:

```
export CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
./configure --target=arm-linux
make
```

And then rename two generated binaries in src directory from lsz and lrz to sz and rz respectively and just copy them into /usr/bin directory of the board. This way you can send and receive files using zmodem inside minicom or any other terminal.